# "Reconcile Offline Work" in Perforce doesn't work for me

Tags: perforce, offline-mode

In the 2009.1 version of Perforce Visual Client for 32-bin Windows, the "Reconcile Offline Work" option does weird things.  In the middle box where the "Local files not in depot" should be displayed, I never get anything.  What I do see is that the first time I reconcile a folder, it looks like perforce is filling the box with the "local files not in depot" because a list flashes quickly before my eyes.  Then all of a sudden, the list quickly disappears into thin air and I'm left with an empty list.  Does anyone know how I can get this feature to show me the files that I have not yet added?  It seems like the "Modified files" and "Depot files missing from workspace" features work fine.

Also, as a side note, "Reconcile Offline Work" seemed to work fine in the 2009 beta version.

Comment: Have you reported this directly to Perforce? Their support is usually very good.

Comment: I just played around with this a bit and something definitely is not right.  I'd take this up with Perforce tech support.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll contact them when I get a chance.

Comment: 4 years later: "reconcile offline work" STILL crashing frequently and exhibiting extremely odd, unreliable behavior on OS X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

The solution for me was obscure but trivial.

I simply changed the root directory of my client workspace from "C:\depot" to "c:\depot".

Yes, that's right, all I did was to change the drive letter from uppercase to lowercase.  And, yes, I verified that changing the drive letter back to uppercase breaks it again and that changing the drive letter back to lowercase again fixes it again.  So, this is not just a coincidence.

This is almost certainly a bug in the Perforce reconcile feature.

If you look closely at the reconcile paths, they all appear with a lowercase drive letter, even if you specify an uppercase drive letter, so my guess is that the matching algorithm is simply doing a case-sensitive comparison on the file paths.  This is appropriate for everything but the drive letter.  Their file lister probably always sets the drive letter to lowercase, so an uppercase drive letter on your client workspace root will never match.

Comment: This definately worked.  Thank you for posting your solution.

Comment: I had the same problem and read Adam's answer several times but failed to spot my error.  I had a folder in the path on my Linux box that was CSi in the depot and CSI in the workspace.  Everything worked except Reconcile Offline Work. After fixing the typo I also have to change to the Workspace tab as Reconcile Offline Work is not (always!) available under the Depot tab. Thank you Adam for guiding me in the right direction!

Comment: Any other solutions? I triple checked the cases of alphabets in my root path. It is the same, but still the damn "Reconcile offline changes" does not show files which are removed from file system & hence the workspace.

Comment: My problem was just that it had somehow switched what workspace I was using (they look identical from the file structure) so I just switched to the right one. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly sometimes happens. I seems the problem is likely to occur if I change the workspace view somehow and/or upgrade P4V to new version. So the solution which worked for me in the past was to trash the problematic workspace and create a new one (sometimes have to choose a different name too).

Perhaps deleting the .p4qt and .p4scc in your user home directory can help too.

Incidently, I did have a conversation with Perforce support on the related subject some time ago, and as the problems like this are very difficult to reproduce, therefore there wasn't much that they could do.

Comment: Having the same exact issue. Did a new workspace as suggested and its working fine indeed.

I also tried removing .p4qt in user home directory and it still didn't work, the .p4scc wasn't there either

Comment: I have a repo here on Windows that has no file names limit and longer than normal paths and reconcile fails repeatedly, not sure if it is related but reconcile works on repos with short file names.  I have tried the c: C: tricks and also -C0 and -C1 for case insensitive repos.  Using a newer version of the tools that has

filesys.windows.lfn=1

on by default, but still reconcile breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found issues with long filenames in p4 reconcile

from the base direectory

p4 reconcile ./...

never returned.

but if I cd further up the tree

cd components
p4 reconcile ./...

worked.

I was able to reconcile the whole tree eventually by stepping up directories, depending on how much longer your paths are this might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had an instance where p4v showed the visual indicator that files had changes, and doing a diff showed the changes appropriately, but resolve on any parent directory didn't show them.

Those files had been changed by downgrading a library using a unity package install, and their "last modified" date was older than the previously submitted files. On OSX running the `touch` command on all the files in relevant directories updated all their modified times and reconcile worked after that.

Comment: Happened to me again and I found my own Stack Overflow answer. This time it was actually an upgrade of that same library, not a downgrade, but still the same last modified date problem.