# How to determine deleted files in perforce

Tags: perforce

I had directory structure A/B, A/C, A/D
and then had few files in each directory B, C, D.

Lets say, in B - B1.txt, B2.txt, B3.txt
IF someone delete B2.txt from perforce and i dont know when, is there any way i can find out what are the files deleted from the directory and at what time?

Answer (score 45):

In P4V you can turn on the option to "Show Deleted Depot Files".

[image]

Deleted depot files will then display, with their file icons having an "x" on them, and you can easily examine their history.

[image]

Comment: I got to know the deleted files in depot as you suggested. But what I wanted and am used to is, I delete files from the file system or Xcode project as and how I feel its not necessary. And when finally when it is time to commit, this piece of shit (p4v) has no way to tell me which files I have deleted from my file system so that I can commit those files to the server marked as 'deleted'. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: @Raj: By working outside of the Perforce interface you are confusing it as to the state of your files.  You should use P4V to delete the files, not a file manager or some other tool.  However, if you really feel you need to use something besides P4V to delete the files (why, I can't imagine), you can use the Perforce option to "Reconcile Offline Work...".  What you are doing is basically [Working Disconnected From The Perforce Server](http://kb.perforce.com/article/2/working-disconnected-from-the-perforce-server).  Read that article for more info.

Comment: Basically am from git background and git does allow people to delete files from outside and it shows the files which were tracked earlier but no longer exists now. So it gives an opportunity to mark those files as deleted. I realised that "Reconcile Offline Work" feature does present us with similar feature, which is good. But unfortunately and probably due to a bug in P4v, it does not list the files which are deleted. This link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324804/reconcile-offline-work-in-perforce-doesnt-work-for-me does discuss that bug, but the solution presented does not help me!

Comment: @Raj: That question is three years old.  Perhaps there was a bug in 2009.1, but it works just fine in 2012.2.  I tested it before I posted my last comment.

Comment: I tested too. My "reconcile offline changes" would not show any files which are deleted in the filesystem.

Answer (score 9):

From the command line, you can type `p4 filelog -t //your_depot/path/to/folder/...` and that will give you the revision history of all the files in "folder" (including subdirectories).

You can search the output of that command for "delete" and that will tell you the revision number for the file when it got deleted, and it should also have the date/time info in there.

Comment: Its not working, perforce is not showing files which are deleted.

Comment: When i tried p4 filelog //depot/A/B/B2.txt, i got error file not on client

Comment: Is //depot/A/B/B2.txt the actual path in Perforce to the file?

Comment: Also I updated my answer to be more explicit that you needed to provide the specific path to the file/folder, and switched to using filelog as it's a better command for the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'd add this as a comment but don't have enough rep.  To simplify the results from command line you could do as follows..

From Linux I use

> p4 files //depot/project/... | grep "delete change"

You can achieve the same in Windows via

> p4 files //depot/project/... | findstr "delete change"

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
p4 files /path/to/dir/...
```

This will list all the files in the directory, even those deleted.
Then, by the `changelist #`, you can get the info you look for by:

```
p4 describe -s <changelist #>
```

Good luck!!!